# Modify node value in all materials with variable name?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I'm trying to automate a process where I have to change a Value node for all materials starting with the prefix `mb:`. I've been messing with it, but I'm such a novice with Python that I'm stuck.

Looking at the console, I see that the code for changing the value of the node would be this:

`bpy.data.materials["mb:o:150:27"].node_tree.nodes["Value"].outputs[0].default_value = 10`

But my issue is that I don't know how I would apply the variable of `mb:` to the to string in the above line.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to iterate over all materials and check each material's name. IF it starts with `'mb:'` then modify it.

```
import bpy 
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if material.name.startswith("mb:"):
        material.node_tree.nodes["Value"].outputs[0].default_value = 10
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had a bit of trouble at first, but this solved it all.